# No progress indicator on Bluemix MQA "Install" of updated iPad app

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

We're using Bluemix to distribute our app over-the-air (OTA). The first time we used the "Install" button in the email, there was no progress indicator, but we could live with it because we knew that installation was complete when the icon appeared on the iPad.

However, when we did a later update of the app and "Install"ed, there is no indication of when the app has completed downloading, and, since there is already an icon on the desktop, we can't figure out if the new app has downloaded.

Our workarounds are

1. just wait a long time and hope that the app has downloaded
2. uninstall the app before we "Install" the new version

I hope I'm missing some other obvious indicator that the app is being downloaded/install. Am I? Or is there install-in-progress indicator when using Bluemix MQA?

Comment: What version of MQA SDK library are you using?

Comment: Bluemix MQA pointed to Q4M.framework-2.2.2(1).zip (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/download_sdks.html , which led to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/IOSSDKsForDownload.html)

Answer (score 1):

We have released the fix for this and you should see the progress indicator on the app now when you do over the air distribution.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8 changed something that was working in previous iOS's when you install OTA builds you no longer see the icon installing on the device. I am opening a request to have this corrected for MQA.